# How to do exact phrase search using contains in sql server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to search terms like "contact and legal information" and want exact phrase rows in result.
Here is a list of query :

```
SELECT * FROM pages_details where contains(title, '"*contact information"')
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `LIKE` operator

```
SELECT * FROM 
pages_details 
where title like '%contact information%'
```